# smooth functions associated to vector fields X associated to charts is well defined

Tags: differential-geometry

I am confused. I am reading this book. Given manifold $(M^n,x)$. First he defines tangent space in the following steps.

Step 1:

Construct $\alpha : (-\epsilon,+\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ continuous such that $\alpha(0) = p$.

$T_pM$ is defined as equivalence class of curves where the relation is defined as

$$\alpha \sim \beta \iff (x \circ \alpha)(0)^{\prime} = (x \circ \beta)(0)^{\prime}$$

A vector field X assigns to each point in the manifold p a vector in the tangent space.

In a coordinate neighborhood (U,x) can be expressed as $\Sigma h_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ where $h_i$ is a function on U. Those $h_i$ is independent of the choice of $(U,x)$.

I don't understand this. How can we compute that it is independent of choice of $(U,x)$.

[image]

Comment: What is supposed to be independent in which sense?

Comment: independent of the choice of charts. The vector field X is independent of choice of charts. I am little bit confused on how to show this.

Comment: Are the $f_i$ supposed to be fixed functions? If so, that vector field surely isn't independent of the choice of chart. If they're not supposed to be fixed, however, I'm not sure what the statement is supposed to say. What book are you reading and can you give the precise statement of what it says?

Comment: I am not sure either. I have attached a screen shot.

Comment: Complex differential geometry by Zheng. Page 6.

Comment: He doesn't say the vector field is independent of the choice of chart, he says that, in each chart, the vector field can be expressed as linear combination of the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and *whether the coefficient functions are smooth or not* is independent of the choice of chart.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Can you explain why the coefficient functions are smooth or not is indepedent of choice of chart ?

Comment: @Thorgott Is it because on the intersection of a coordinate neighbourhood we have that the functions are the same. I am not understanding this clearly. If you could clear this up that would be great.

Comment: Does Zheng specify that $M$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ (or maybe $\Bbb C^n$)? I ask because your definition of $T_pM$ requires curves come with pre-defined derivatives. There are more general definitions where this is not the case.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, he uses local coordinates to move from M to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$. Though he doesn't say it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that on the coordinate patch $(U, x)$ for all $i$,
$$X(x_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n h_j\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = h_i$$

So $h_i = X(x_i)$. Because both $X$ and $x_i$ are smooth, so is $h_i$. This is true regardless of the particular coordinate system $(U, x)$ used.